# Can mysql send signals to the outer world

Tags: mysql

I need to execute a system command every time a specific mysql table is updated. Is it possible? Is mysql able to somehow let the system know that a table has been updated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this UDF](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/).

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this: http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/424231-trigger-run-external-program
However, I recommend that you just include it in the programs that access your database. At least, you can customize it better than just putting them in your query.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible to get last updated date of the table.

```
select update_time from information_schema.TABLES where table_schema='<database>' and table_name='<table>';
```

at a specific time interval you can fetch the updated time and check with last updated time.